# How do I get LastActivity and LastActivityAge in Case

Tags: acumatica

I am referring to Send Case Reminder project in GitHub where it has LastActivity and LastActivityAge for each case based on which it calculates days and send automatic email notifications.

However, for some reason it is not present in my cases when I implemented the project. So here is what I did.

I created a simple GI from CRCase table and just added three columns to the ResultsGrid, viz. CaseCD, LastActivity & LastActivityAge. What I get is there is no values in LastActivity & LastActivityAge columns for all cases. I am not sure how it works or how should I get the values for these two fields.

I have also checked CRActivityStatistics table for LastIncomingActivityDate and LastOutgoingActivityDate fields. And these two fields has values for all the cases.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
PS. I am using 2018 R2 ver 18.201.0050.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do see expected data within the CRActivityStatistics but don’t see the proper values on your GI that would suggest that your join relationship might be incorrect.  This could be the issue in your GI and in your code.  The proper join is CRCASE.NOTEID = CRACTIVITYSTATISTICS.NOTEID.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of this joins though as I have already mentioned in the initial question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this through DAC extension

```html
#region LastIncomingActivityDate
        public abstract class lastIncomingActivityDate : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        [PXDBDate(BqlField = typeof(CRActivityStatistics.lastIncomingActivityDate), PreserveTime = true, UseSmallDateTime = false)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Incoming Activity")]
        public virtual DateTime? LastIncomingActivityDate { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region LastOutgoingActivityDate
        public abstract class lastOutgoingActivityDate : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        [PXDBDate(BqlField = typeof(CRActivityStatistics.lastOutgoingActivityDate), PreserveTime = true, UseSmallDateTime = false)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Outgoing Activity")]
        public virtual DateTime? LastOutgoingActivityDate { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region LastActivityDate
        public abstract class lastActivityDate : IBqlField { }
        [PXDBCalced(typeof(Switch<
                Case<Where<lastIncomingActivityDate, IsNotNull, And<lastOutgoingActivityDate, IsNull>>, lastIncomingActivityDate,
                Case<Where<lastOutgoingActivityDate, IsNotNull, And<lastIncomingActivityDate, IsNull>>, lastOutgoingActivityDate,
                Case<Where<lastIncomingActivityDate, Greater<lastOutgoingActivityDate>>, lastIncomingActivityDate>>>,
            lastOutgoingActivityDate>),
            typeof(DateTime))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Activity Date", Enabled = false)]
        [PXDate]
        public virtual DateTime? LastActivityDate { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region UsrLastActivityAge
        public abstract class usrLastActivityAge : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        [PXTimeSpanLong(InputMask = "#### ds ## hrs ## mins")]
        [PXFormula(typeof(Sub<PXDateAndTimeAttribute.now, lastActivityDate>))]
        [PXDefault(0)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Activity Age")]
        public virtual Int32? UsrLastActivityAge { get; set; }
        #endregion
```